# How do I delete window using a button

Tags: python

*So far in my code I show a couple of examples and then ask if the user is ready to take the quiz. I would like to make the window that has the examples to disappear once I press the button that says Yes but I was told I cannot use to commands in one button. What would be the best way to delete the window? *

```
from tkinter import  *
root= Tk()

def clickEvent1():
   master = Tk()

   mainloop()




def clickEvent2():

    master = Tk()
    Label2=Label(master, text="Here are the scientific names of some Animals", font=("Times", 13) )
    Label2.pack()
    Label3=Label(master, text="Wolf=Canis lupus", font=("Arial", 11))
    Label3.pack()
    Label4=Label(master, text="Lion=Panthera leo",font=("Arial", 11))
    Label4.pack()
    Label5=Label(master, text="Panda=Ailuropoda melanoleuca", font=("Arial", 11))
    Label5.pack()
    Label6=Label(master, text="Jellyfish=Medusozoa", font=("Arial", 11))
    Label6.pack()
    Label7=Label(master, text="Marmoset=Callithrix jacchus", font=("Arial", 11))
    Label7.pack()
    Label8=Label(master, text="Tiger=Panthera tigris", font=("Arial", 11))
    Label8.pack()
    Label9=Label(master, text="Zebra=Equus quagga", font=("Arial", 11))
    Label9.pack()
    Label0=Label(master, text="Would you like to take the quiz now?", font=("Arial", 13))
    Label0.pack()
    button3=Button(master, text="Yes", font=("Arial", 12), fg="White",bg="Turquoise",height=1, width=10, command=clickEvent1 )
    button3.pack()
    mainloop()
```

*The code above is where the yes button is used and where the command to make a new window is called.*

```
mylabel=Label(root, text="Welcome to the Animal Trivia Game!", font=("Arial", 14))
mylabel.pack()
label2=Label(root, text="Click 'Start' to begin:)", font=("Arial", 14))
label2.pack()
topFrame=Frame(root)
topFrame.pack()
bottomFrame=Frame(root)
bottomFrame.pack(side=BOTTOM)
leftFrame=Frame(root)
leftFrame.pack(side=LEFT)
rightFrame=Frame(root)
rightFrame.pack(side=RIGHT)
button1=Button(topFrame,text="Start", font=("Arial", 16), fg="White",bg="Turquoise",height=1, width=10,command=clickEvent2)
button1.pack()
mainloop()
```

Comment: Are you trying to run multiple main loops? You shouldn't do that! It won't work. Instead look at the `TopLevel` widget.

Comment: Your mainloop isn't even defined, despite the fact that you should not have more than one